# String value becomes undefined when trying to concat another string

Tags: javascript, api, scope, global-variables

I'm working on practicing with the openweathermap api. I have a coordinate object with keys lat & lon which are equal to a string. When I pass that coord obj into another function and try to concat those strings with the api call string they become undefined. I thought I made the scope of these variables global but it doesn't seem to be the case. Can someone tell me what is incorrect about this code

```
var apikey = '9575f3355ae129dc91424b5712a7695e';
var coords = {};
var accessOWM='';

function myLocation(){        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)       {
    coords.lat = (Math.round(position.coords.latitude*100)/100).toString();
    coords.lon = (Math.round(position.coords.longitude*100)/100).toString();
  });
}

function changeAccess(coordObj, key){
console.log(coordObj);
accessOWM ='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat='+coordObj['lat']+'&lon='+coordObj['lon']+'&APPID='+key;
}


myLocation();
console.log(coords);
changeAccess(coords, apikey);
console.log(accessOWM);
```

Comment: That's because [`getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) is **asynchronous**. So when you call `changeAccess` `getCurrentPosition` is not completed yet. You have to place `changeAccess` call into `getCurrentPosition` callback

Comment: why do you need it to be string? javascript can handle that

Comment: Thanks all, I always struggle to remember when a function call is asynchronous and how to navigate that correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because [`getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) method is **asynchronous**. This mean that `getCurrentPosition`'s callback is not invoked at the moment of calling `changeAccess` function. So you have to place `changeAccess` call into `getCurrentPosition`'s callback:

```
function myLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        coords.lat = (Math.round(position.coords.latitude*100)/100).toString();
        coords.lon = (Math.round(position.coords.longitude*100)/100).toString();
    });
    changeAccess(coords, apikey);
}
```

Comment: @Rawle Juglal You could upvote this answer if it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with async code. `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback)` function is an asyncronious function, the `successCallback` will not be executed immedeately, but with some delay. That is why when you call `console.log(coords)` and `changeAccess(coords, apiKey)`, the coords are not defined yet. You need to call these functions (and the last one) from inside the `.getCurrentPosition()` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Since coords is declared in the parent scope of changeAccess, you don't need to pass coordObj into changeAccess. Have you tried:

```
 accessOWM ='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat='+ coords.lat + '&lon=' + coords.lon + '&APPID='+key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
var apikey = '9575f3355ae129dc91424b5712a7695e';
var accessOWM;

function round(v){ return Math.round(v*100)/100 }

function myLocation(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        changeAccess(position.coords);
    });
}

function changeAccess(coords){
    console.log(coordObj);
    accessOWM ='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=' + round(coords.latitude) + '&lon=' + round(coords.longitude) + '&APPID=' + apikey;
    console.log(accessOWM);
}

myLocation();
```

Or

```
var apikey = '9575f3355ae129dc91424b5712a7695e';
var accessOWM = myLocation().then(changeAccess);

accessOWM.then(function(v){
    console.log(v);
})

function round(v){ return Math.round(v*100)/100 }

function myLocation(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            resolve(position.coords);
        });
    });
}

function changeAccess(coords){
    return 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=' + round(coords.latitude) + '&lon=' + round(coords.longitude) + '&APPID=' + apikey;
}
```